# ng-click adds a class on all elements instead of just one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a matrix created with the following code:

```
<div class="cell-container" ng-repeat="cell in field">
    <div ng-repeat="cols in cell track by $index" class="cell" ng-click="selectShip(cols)" ng-class="{ selected: !cols.empty }">
        {{ $parent.$index }} {{ $index }} 
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside the directive I have a function that when clicked should change the object value and add a class to the clicked element

```
scope: {
    field: '=',
    type: '@'
},
link: function($scope) {
    $scope.selectShip = function(item) {
        if ( item.empty === true ) {
            item.empty = false;
        } else {
            item.empty = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I click on a div in the inner ng-repeat, it changes the object value and adds a class on all the divs, not just the clicked one.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Where are you using your directive in the HTML or your page?

Comment: I dont understand the question

Comment: This template you've shown in question is it of directive's template or template of you page (partial view or route)?

Comment: Its a directive template.

Answer (score 0):

It must be because you are making use of `$scope`. Instead you should use an isolated scope to have a separate scope for all the directive elements created.
Directives in angular inherit the parent scope by default.
You can find some help here - [How to create an isolate scope](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope)

Comment: There is a isolated scope created already. Take a look at the first lines of directive code.

Comment: But you are not using it in the link function -  `$scope.selectShip = function(item) {`